# Error when executing .vbs or .wsf

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript

I get an error everytime I start a .vbs Script.
Double-click:

```
Skriptmodul "VBScript" für Skript "C:\test.vbs" wurde nicht gefunden.
```

[image]

Run via CMD:

```
CScript-Fehler: Skriptmodul "VBScript" für Skript "C:\test.vbs" wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I executed "*regsvr32.exe VBScript*", "*regsvr32.exe jscript.dll*" and "*regsvr32.exe jscript.dll*" via admin CMD (in system32) and both got registered correctly. I checked file date and size of the .dlls with other Windows clients, they match exactly.
Active Scripting and Java Applets are enabled in the internet options.

Searching with System File Checker (sfc.exe) for corrupted system files found some, repaired them, nothing changed after reboot.

Similiar problem with .wsf Scripts.
This error appears no matter which .wsf script I execute.
[image: .wsf script error]

Guys, any idea how to fix this one?

Comment: try setting the OS to english then re-running, you may then get an error message that is readable.  (SO is a English web site)

Comment: I think that we are not allowed to change the screen language of our office pcs. Apart from the fact that no other display language is installed and Windows update doesn't provide any LIP (controlled WSUS behind)... :-/

Comment: I think the error should be: "Can't find script engine "VBScript" for script [...]", [mentioned here](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/209/1/Error-Cant-find-script-engine-VBScript-for-script-when-installing-the-Windows-Installer-Cleanup-Utility.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed it myself:

In the registry, this key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}\InprocServer32
```

was modified by our antivirus vendor McAfee -.-

The (standard) key was changed to

```
C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\McAfee\\SystemCore\\ScriptSn.20110513152421.dll
```

and no changes were allowed so that regsvr32 could not update this key.

I had to modify the permissions on this reg key to get full access and changed it to

```
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\vbscript.dll"
```

Both .vbs and .wsf scripts are working again! *sigh* 
I just hate McAfee in an enterprise environment.

I've writte down **6 possible solutions for this script problem** here (but it's in german, sorry ^^): [6 solutions for .vbs and .wsf script error](http://hannes-schurig.de/10/08/2011/fehler-beim-ausfuhren-von-vbs-und-wsf-skripten-skriptmodul-vbscript-nicht-gefunden/)